# wget in bash loop not working, but works for single request

Tags: bash, wget

I want to download files 1 by 1 using wget and get contents with CURL.

I have a sn.txt file with item numbers like:

```
1234
2345
3456
4567
```

The URLs I want is:

```
http://myweb.com/items/item-check?item=1234
http://myweb.com/items/item-check?item=2345
http://myweb.com/items/item-check?item=3456
http://myweb.com/items/item-check?item=4567
```

If I run:

```
#!/bin/bash
TempFile="tmp/item.$(date +%s).txt"
while read sn; do

   echo Checking Item Number: $sn

until grep -q "$sn" itemlist.txt; do
    wget http://myweb.com/items/item-check?item=$sn -O $TempFile

GetaDiv()
{
grep -A 98 '<div class="main-info">' ${TempFile} |grep -A 2 '<div class="field">'
}

aDiv=$(GetaDiv)
(echo "${aDiv}") >> itemlist.txt
done
echo "Done! Item ADDED SUCCESSFULLY"
done < sn.txt
```

This code above fails to get any results.. If I run this same code for ONLY 1 URL then it works fine.

This works fine:

```
#!/bin/bash
TempFile="tmp/item.$(date +%s).txt"
while read sn; do

   echo Checking Item Number: $sn

until grep -q "$sn" itemlist.txt; do
    wget http://myweb.com/items/item-check?item=1234 -O $TempFile

GetaDiv()
{
grep -A 98 '<div class="main-info">' ${TempFile} |grep -A 2 '<div class="field">'
}

aDiv=$(GetaDiv)
(echo "${aDiv}") >> itemlist.txt
done
echo "Done! Item ADDED SUCCESSFULLY"
done < sn.txt
```

Why can't I run all links in this bash loop file? It's working fine for single request. It looks like bash is not waiting for wget to finish.

Comment: You are saving files with same name using -O option, so you will see only one file as it gets overwritten with each wget query.

Comment: @MaheshKharvi: Yes, in ever LOOP at the end the contents from GREP is saved to itemlist.txt before getting content from NEXT link and updating itemslist.txt again and again...

Comment: @MaheshKharvi: By the way the file is NOT same. I get NEW files for every wget query, since file name is: item. ''$(date +%s).txt'' so the filename is dependent of what time its created.. therefore unique name for all files.

Comment: TempFile is not dynamic as you have defined that outside while loop, you can echo $TempFile to see what value is assigned.You should try moving your function to main body and pass tempFile as input.